# SQL order by original column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which re-formats the timedisposed column to display in a better format. This is needed to be named "timedisposed" so that it shows correctly in our software. I noticed however, the order by timedisposed goes off of the altered formatted "AS" timedisposed column and not the original. This causes dates of December to show before January. How can I order by the original timedisposed, and not the timedisposed I reformatted?

```
SELECT top 100 ORDNO,convert(varchar(10),TIMEDISPOSED, 101) + right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEDISPOSED,100),8) as TIMEDISPOSED,ORIGREC 
FROM DLOCATION 
WHERE DISPOSED = 'Y' 
ORDER BY TIMEDISPOSED DESC
```

Comment: December would show before (returned first / above / etc) January when ordered `DESC`. Maybe you want `ASC`?

Comment: Yet another example of why you should leave formatting to the front end. If you returned datetime data to the application layer it could be ordered there any way it wants and it could also present it in any format. Once you format date information you lose all the flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, you can specify the column name like `DLOCATION.TIMEDISPOSED`.

```
SELECT top 100 ORDNO,convert(varchar(10),TIMEDISPOSED, 101) + right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEDISPOSED,100),8) as TIMEDISPOSED,ORIGREC 
FROM DLOCATION 
WHERE DISPOSED = 'Y' 
ORDER BY DLOCATION.TIMEDISPOSED DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the only way that you have to force a specific order is through the use of Order By, in this case, you only should add the ASC to your query, I mean:

```
SELECT top 100 ORDNO,convert(varchar(10),TIMEDISPOSED, 101) + 
right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEDISPOSED,100),8) as TIMEDISPOSED_Calc,ORIGREC 
FROM DLOCATION 
WHERE DISPOSED = 'Y' 
ORDER BY TIMEDISPOSED ASC
```

However, remember that ORDER operator has a cost and you always should consider if it is cheaper ORDER inside the app instead of Database.

Comment: You might be right about the sort order, but your query would still be ordering by the aliased column, not the original `TIMEDISPOSED` column.